# Facebook login dialog appear again after login in

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I implemented the facebook login for android according to their documentation

The problem is that after the user enter its credentials (1 dialog) for login and confirm the app permissions (2 dialog) the facebook connect simply return to the (1 dialog) where its request the credentials again. why is this happening?

In the facebook user i can see the app in the apps list

This is my code:

```
CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile","user_friends");
    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            Log.i(Utils.TAG,"succesfull login to facebook");

            // App code
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                            try {
                            }catch (Exception e)
                            {   Log.i(Utils.TAG, e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Log.i(Utils.TAG,"onCancel login to facebook");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.i(Utils.TAG,"onError login to facebook");
            Log.i(Utils.TAG,exception.getMessage());
        }
    });



    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
    //        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions((Activity)m_context, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions((Activity)m_context, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i(Utils.TAG,"onActivityResult called");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I should mention that none of the call backs is called during the login flow only when i dismiss the dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, It is because you are using login button and Login Manager both.. You have to choose only one from them.. because they both have same functionality.   I suggest you to remove Login Manager code from here.

```
 loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
        //        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions((Activity)m_context, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions((Activity)m_context, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
            }
        });
```

and

```
oginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            Log.i(Utils.TAG,"succesfull login to facebook");

            // App code
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                            try {
                            }catch (Exception e)
                            {   Log.i(Utils.TAG, e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Log.i(Utils.TAG,"onCancel login to facebook");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.i(Utils.TAG,"onError login to facebook");
            Log.i(Utils.TAG,exception.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because facebook login api uses chrome browser. After you log in once, chrome browser holds that. If you log out facebook in chrome browser, the '1 dialog' may appear.